# Match Function Nested in Index Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to nest MATCH functions into an INDEX function to find the ending balance (column name) of the 34th month (row) with two named ranges: `my_data` and `my_data_2`.

The data table has labeled columns across the top with the ending balance column being labeled "Ending Balance". There are no row headers. The first column is labeled "Month" and the values in the column are months passed since the start of the loan.

The named range label `my_data` I have assigned to all rows except the column headers.

The name range label `my_data_2` I have assigned to the row of column headers.

[image: image of table]

**This is what I tried:**

```
=INDEX(my_data, MATCH("34", my_data), MATCH("Ending Balance", my_data_2))
```

gives `#N/A` error

I expected the Match functions to find the row labeled "34" and use it at the row index, and find the column named "Ending Balance" and use it as the column index to find a value in the my_data range.

Am I doing something wrong with the named ranges?

Comment: Test the matches to see what they return.

Comment: The second match problem is the issue, MATCH("Ending Balance", my_data_2) won't return anything

Comment: It seems that `my_data` is either 1 column, so the second match returning 5 references the 5th column of a 1 column range. If `my_data` is multiple columns than the first match is the issue, it should be indexed to the correct column.

Comment: In this case it seems a lookup could work as well: `=LOOKUP(34,A3:E75)` ?

Comment: If Month is in column A, then index(E:E,match(34,A:A,1,0)) should work.

Answer (score 2):

### A Nested `INDEX/MATCH`

- The `MATCH` function has 3 arguments. The 3rd set to `0` means *"exact match"*.
- When looking for numbers, don't put them in quotes (`34`, not `"34"`).
- You're looking for `34` in the first column of the data range which is `INDEX(my_data,,1)` (not `my_data`).
- `my_headers` is a much more appropriate name than `my_data_2`.

```
=INDEX(my_data,
    MATCH(34,INDEX(my_data,,1),0),
    MATCH("Ending Balance",my_headers,0))
```

[image]

- Note that in your particular case (your screenshot), since the 34th month is in the 34th row of the data range, the formula could be simplified:

  ```
  =INDEX(my_data,34,MATCH("Ending Balance",my_headers,0))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can just use `FILTER()`. Just use different names, columnwise.

In this example:

1. Assign names `Month` to first column and `EndBal` to last column.
2. Type

`=FILTER(EndBal,Month=34)`

Done.